# LD_PRELOAD not working with my program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, ld-preload

For testing LD_PRELOAD, I wrote my own `getpid`, which prints something before calling the original `getpid` using dlsym. The code is given below.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef pid_t (*getpidType)(void);

pid_t getpid(void)
{
    printf("Hello, getpid!\n");
    getpidType f = (getpidType)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getpid");
    return f();
}
```

However when I use such `getpid` in my program and run it using LD_PRELOAD, by typing `LD_PRELOAD=./prelib.so ./prog`,  I get the following error.

```
./prog: symbol lookup error: ./prelib.so: undefined symbol: dlsym
```

But If I do `LD_PRELOAD=./prelib.so bash -c 'echo $$'`, there is no such error. Any idea what is going on here.

Comment: Do you link with `-ldl`?

Comment: Did you `export` it? I.e. `export LD_PRELOAD` afterward. It's an environment variable, so it must be exported like so at some point.

Comment: Link what, my program or compiling the library to be LD_PRELOADed?

Comment: FatalError: I think you need to export for LD_LIBRARY_PATH, not for LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: @FatalError - the call `LD_PRELOAD=./prelib.so ./prog` is equivalent to exporting `LD_PRELOAD` before calling `./prog`

Comment: Turn on LD_DEBUG and see what it tells you. It looks like it's failing to find dlsym in the first place, which, as per @NikolaiNFetissov, seems requires -ldl. I can't explain why it works with bash if you left that out.

Comment: @bmargulies: Probably because bash uses libdl. You can see this by running `ldd /bin/bash`

Comment: Indeed, as long as the main program links `libdl`, it's already loaded in the global symbol space and the `.so` doesn't need to explicitly depend on it. But to work in all cases, the `.so` does not to explicitly pull it in.

Answer (score 5):

Linking it with `libdl.so.2` by using `-ldl` in the makefile solved the problem.