# How can I tell GCC to use custom library for -l instead of the system one?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I have a custom build of SQLite3 at `/somepath`, so `/somepath/.libs` contains `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` and the symbolic links to it. I wanted to link a program against it and assumed

```
g++ -O3 -g -fPIC -I /somepath -I /somepath/src -L /somepath/.libs -lsqlite3 -o myfile.so myfile.cpp
```

would work. It compiles, but I get a segmentation fault due to some problem in my code, and when trying to debug I run into the issues which look like [LD_PRELOAD not working with my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703413/ld-preload-not-working-with-my-program) and [Setting my lib for LD_PRELOAD makes some processes produce loader errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385155/setting-my-lib-for-ld-preload-makes-some-processes-produce-loader-errors): I can run `LD_PRELOAD=myfile.so /somepath/sqlite3 ...`, but under GDB I get symbol lookup error and `LD_DEBUG=all LD_PRELOAD=myfile.so gdc -c core /somepath/sqlite3 ...` reveals symbols are getting looked up in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0` instead of `/somepath/libsqlite3.so.0`, and unsurprisingly missing the symbols for functions added in the custom build. How can I fix this and debug my code?

Comment: The title contradicts the question. Are you asking on how to make gdb to load your library or gcc to link with your library?

Comment: @SergeyA What I _think_ is that gcc isn't linking to the library I want, but I could be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-lsqlite3` argument should be last. Order of arguments to `g++` matters a lot. You should read more about runpath and perhaps pass `-Wl,-rpath,/somepath/.libs`

You may want to pass `-v` once to `g++`  to understand what is happening (what programs are actually running). You might also pass `-Wl,--verbose` to ask a more verbose link.

Then you can use `ldd` on your executable (and also `readelf`) to find out more what are its link time dependencies.

With suitable arguments to `g++` you should not need *additional* options to `gdb`

Answer (score 2):

From http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_solib-search-path

Inside gdb use the commands below.

```
set solib-search-path [Directories]
show solib-search-path
```